# Draw multiple charts using chart.js at different locations?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using following code to draw multiple charts on a single page at different locations.

```
window.onload = function(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
responsive: true
});

var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx2).Line(lineChartData2, {
    responsive: true
});
}
```

This draws charts together one after other. I want to draw them at different location with some text between them. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you need to change the ctx to ctx2 at the = new chart(ctx)... line for your second chart.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Are the canvasses in the same div then ? If so put them in seperate ones and move the divs